# RxJS subscribe and local variable is null issue

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have written this function in my Angular application to call a RESTful service, the class is outside a Component as a service class

```
getProducts(): IProduct[] {
    let productsObservable = this.http.get<IProduct[]>(this.productUrl).pipe(
        tap(data => console.log("All: " + JSON.stringify(data))),
        catchError(this.serviceErrorHandler)
    );

    let products: IProduct[];
    let errorMessage: string = "";

    productsObservable.subscribe(
        p => {
            products = p;
            console.log("All in subscribe: " + JSON.stringify(products));
        },
        error => errorMessage = <any>error
    );

    if (errorMessage.length > 0) {
        console.log(errorMessage);
        throw new Error(errorMessage);
    }

    console.log("All before return: " + JSON.stringify(products));
    return products;
}
```

I have 3 lines of code with `console.log` to track my data.

- The first one in `tap` function has all JSON data displayed in console, it means the service call is successful.
- The second one in my `subscribe` function also displays the JSON payload.
- But the last one failed. I set a break point to the list console log function and found out that the variable `products` is null.

If the consumer of Http Observable is in the same service class, the result is null. If I break the consumer of service request into Angular's component class, it works fine. What makes the Rx's Observable so strange? I think I soon as I `subscribe` to it, it will be executed.

Any idea what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Is this function in your service file or component file?

Comment: This is a function in my service file.

Answer (score 1):

Yup, this happens because the function passed to `subscribe` is not invoked before you return the `products` list.

Consider a simpler example:

```
function f() {
    let flag: boolean = false;

    setTimeout(() => flag = true, 10);

    return flag;
}
```

With `setTimeout`, you put a new task on the [JavaScript Event Loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop), just like with `http.get`. Tasks on the event loop are always executed **after** the function that put them there returns. In my example, the return value will always be `false`, no matter how low the timeout is.

Coming back to your example, what you need is to return an `Observable` from your function. Instead of trying to assign the return value of the GET call to a local `products` variable, you directly return the GET call. Like this:

```
getProducts(): Observable<IProduct[]> {
    // your get call ...
    return productsObservable;
}
```

Now, this will probably not solve everything for you, because you now need to deal with the `Observable` in your consumer functions. But that's more or less the point of the whole Observable pattern.. to notify the end-consumer of data changes.

In Angular, you can deal with Observables [using the async pipe](https://toddmotto.com/angular-ngif-async-pipe).

Comment: I see what you talk about here. I tried to break my function into 2 in the same class, it still does not work. But If I move Observable consuming code into my component class it works. I don't quite understand why.

Comment: Basically, if you want to use an Observable, you have to pass it through to your end-consumer, in your case the Angular Component.

Comment: What about my end consumer is in the same class?

Comment: You may want to post revised code where you have split your original function into two. There is a chance that same issue exists in the revised code as well. Your second function may have subscribed the first function, but second function returns even before 'subscribe' receives data from first function.